# PHP Upload ajax de arquivos diversos sem submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Preciso fazer um upload sem sair da página, acredito que o melhor seria ajax, correto?

Achei alguns post aqui no SOpt, mas não consegui adaptar a minha necessidade.

Preciso enviar esses dois campos, um de arquivo e outro de texto oculto.

```
<input type="file" id="id-input-file-2" name="arquivo" class="form-control arquivo" />
<input type="hidden" name="onde" id="onde" value="cotacao">
```

.

```
$(".listaArquivo").click(function () {
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    var arquivo = $(".arquivo").val();
    var onde = $("#onde").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'cotacoesEditarUpload.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) { // Avalia se tem suporte a propriedade upload
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function () {
                    /* faz alguma coisa durante o progresso do upload */
                }, false);
            }
        return myXhr;
        }
    });
});
```

Como fazer para assim que for selecionado o arquivo **seja ele qual for**, seja enviado via ajax incluindo o campo oculto?

Não quero usar botão, somente selecionar e enviar.

Comment: @IvanFerrer esse tópico mencionado foi um dos que já vi, mas nos testes que fiz não consegui nenhum sucesso.

Comment: Bom, é bem simples de fazer isso, só seguir esse tutorial: http://www.devmedia.com.br/upload-de-imagens-sem-dar-refresh-utilizando-php-e-jquery/22190

Comment: Aqui tem outro exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932027/upload-multiple-files-with-ajax-and-jquery basta trocar o método `$.each()` pelo da resposta aceita.

Comment: Não é duplicata, pois há um drag drop no que ele pede.

Comment: você quer enviar arquivo usando ajax?

Answer (score 1):

### Drag Drop API:

por: [devbridge](https://github.com/devbridge)

Funciona em:

- IE10+
- Firefox 15+
- Chrome 22+
- Safari 6+
- Opera 12+

**Ficará com essas funcionalidades:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="body">
        <div>
            <h1>HTML5 Ajax Uploader</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="dragndropimage" class="uploadimage-dragndrop">
            <div class="uploadimage-text">Arraste as imagens aqui/div>
            <div>Ou, se preferir</div>
            <div class="uploadimage-input">
                <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="uploadFiles" id="upload-input" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="upload-liveuploads" data-bind="template: { name: 'template-uploads' }"></div>
```

### Script da API:

```
        <script type="text/html" id="template-uploads">
            <div data-bind="visible: showTotalProgress()">
                <div>
                    <span data-bind="text: uploadSpeedFormatted()"></span>
                    <span data-bind="text: timeRemainingFormatted()" style="float: right;"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="uploadimage-totalprogress">
                    <div class="uploadimage-totalprogressbar" style="width: 0%;" data-bind="style: { width: totalProgress() + '%' }"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="foreach: uploads">
                <div class="uploadimage-upload" data-bind="css: { 'uploadimage-uploadcompleted': uploadCompleted() }">
                    <div class="uploadimage-fileinfo">
                        <strong data-bind="text: fileName"></strong>
                        <span data-bind="text: fileSizeFormated"></span>
                        <span class="uploadimage-progresspct" data-bind="visible: uploadProgress() < 100"><span data-bind="text: uploadSpeedFormatted()"></span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uploadimage-progress">
                        <div class="uploadimage-progressbar" style="width: 0%;" data-bind="style: { width: uploadProgress() + '%' }"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>


        <script type="text/javascript" data-main="/scripts/main" src="/Scripts/require.js"></script>

    </div>
```

> Esta é uma API perfeita para a sua necessidade. Você pode arrastar uma imagem ou selecionar que **AUTOMATICAMENTE** o upload será realizado.

### [DOWNLOAD COMPLETO](https://github.com/devbridge/html5-file-uploader)